# CoreData relation saved two over and over again

Tags: json, swift, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a "Listing" entity with a relation to manny with "Tags". I save the data at one from json like this:

```swift
         func saveData(contex: NSManagedObjectContext) {
            
            listings.forEach() { (data) in
                   
            let listingFetch: NSFetchRequest<Listing> = Listing.fetchRequest()
              listingFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@",  "\(Int64(data.id))")
                   
                do {
                 let results:[Listing] = try contex.fetch(listingFetch)
                    if results.count == 0 {

                       let entity = Listing(context: contex)
                        
                        entity.id = Int64(data.id)
                        entity.title = data.title
                        entity.name = data.name
                        data.tags.forEach { (tagData) in
                            let tag = Tag(context: contex)
                            tag.tagName = (tagData)
                            tag.toListing = entity
                            
                        }
                        data.images.forEach { (galleryData) in
                            let image = Gallery(context: contex)
                            image.imageName = galleryData
                            image.galtolisting = entity
                        }
                        
                        try? contex.save()
                        print ("Insert Listing: ID: \(entity.id); Title: \(String(describing: entity.title)); Tags: \(String(describing: data.tags)); Images: \(String(describing: data.images))")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       let entity = results[0]
                        entity.id = Int64(data.id)
                        entity.title = data.title
                        entity.name = data.name
                        data.tags.forEach { tagData in
                            let tag = Tag(context: contex)
                            tag.tagName = tagData
                            tag.toListing = entity
                        }
                        data.images.forEach { galleryData in
                            let image = Gallery(context: contex)
                            image.imageName = galleryData
                            image.galtolisting = entity
                        }
                        try? contex.save()
                        print ("Updated Listing: ID: \(entity.id); Title: \(String(describing: entity.title)); Tags: \(String(describing: data.tags)); Images: \(String(describing: data.images))")
                        
                    }
                    
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("error inserting / updating Listing \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            }
      
        }
```

The problem i have is that when i fetch again to update the data, all the "Tags" are duplicated.

"Listing" entity contrains are set to id.

Comment: If a Listing already exists you add all the tags from the json without checking if they already exists for that Listing object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final.. working code. New tags get saved on top of old ones.

```swift
           data.tags.forEach { (tagData) in
                            let tagFetch: NSFetchRequest<Tag> = Tag.fetchRequest()
                            tagFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "tagName = %@",  tagData)
                            
                            do {
                                let tagresults:[Tag] = try contex.fetch(tagFetch)
                                if tagresults.count == 0 {
                                    if tagData.count > 0 {
                                        let tag = Tag(context: contex)
                                        tag.tagName = (tagData)
                                        tag.toListing = entity
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch let error as NSError {
                                print("error inserting / updating Listing \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                            }
                            
                        }
```

NOW. in have to find a way to delete the tags from CD if they dont exist in the incoming update. EX the user edited the listing and remove some tags!

Comment: `"tagName = %@",  tagData`, is this really working? Isn’t tagData a Tag object?

Comment: Yes! i have no error. New tags from json are saved in CD. Bit this way i only add is not a complete update, if the tags get removed from json they are still in CD, do you havean idea how can i remove only the tags witch are not contained?

Comment: One approach is to remove all tags and then add the new ones. Another way is to use two Set objects instead of arrays to compare the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Every time this line runs:

```
let tag = Tag(context: contex)
```

You're telling Core Data to create a new `Tag`. If you don't want to create a new `Tag`, you need to find instances that already exist and update them. You could do this by

- Fetching `Tag` with a predicate based on `tagName`. Check to see if a `Tag` with that name already exists. If so, update it. If not, create a new one. This is easier but probably slower.
- Fetching all `Tag` instances and keeping them in a dictionary where the keys are the `tagName`. Then you can look in the dictionary to see if the necessary `Tag` exists and either create one or update the one you already have. This isn't hard but isn't quite as easy, but will probably be faster.

Comment: This answer assumes a many-to-many relationship, I got the impression it is a one-to-many relationship OP is using although it is most likely better with a many-to-many